# How to install pjsua2 library in python using buildroot?

Tags: python, arm, pjsip, buildroot, pjsua2

I installed libpjsip-2.13 using buildroot on arm cortex-A7 processor. The problem I have is that in order to use pjsua2 in python I need to have access to the libpjsip-2.13 folder on the board so I can install it manually as the [documentation](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#building-java-python-and-c-swig-modules) explains.
But when I put the buildroot image on the sdcard, I don't have access to the libpjsip-2.13 folder. So how should I install python on it?